# Forfiles will cause this batch-file to hang after the last Y/N confirmation, and delete the specified directories, after which errors are generated

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, forfiles

I'm not looking for any work around, unless `Forfiles` has an issue.

I need to know my mistakes with this.

NOTE-01: The prompt below is via `pushd`. No matter if via `pushd` or the local machines' terminal; the results remain the same.

```
W:\TEMP_TESTING_Copy>dir /a:d /b
20230326
20230327
20230328
20230329
20230330
```

old.bat Version 01:

```bash
@echo off
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
 
ForFiles /p "X:\TEMP_TESTING_Copy" /s /d -03/27/2023 /c "cmd /c IF @isdir==TRUE rd /S @PATH"
```

```
W:\TEMP_TESTING_Copy>old

X:\TEMP_TESTING_Copy\20230326, Are you sure (Y/N)? n

X:\TEMP_TESTING_Copy\20230327, Are you sure (Y/N)? n

^CTerminate batch job (Y/N)? y  <-- She hangs until manually terminated.
```

old.bat Version 02:

```bash
@echo off
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

ForFiles /p "X:\TEMP_TESTING_Copy" /s /d -03/27/2023 /c "cmd /c IF @isdir==TRUE rd /S /Q @PATH"
```

```
W:\TEMP_TESTING_Copy>old
    

ERROR: The system cannot find the file specified.

ERROR: The system cannot find the file specified.

Press any key to continue . . .
   
W:\TEMP_TESTING_Copy>

W:\TEMP_TESTING_Copy>dir /a:d /b

20230328
20230329
20230330
```

Obviously the specified directories and their contents were removed\deleted.

```
W:\TEMP_TESTING_Copy>dir /b
20230328
20230329
20230330
cln.bat
dd.bat
delete_.txt
napa.txt
old.bat
old.bat - Shortcut.lnk
```

I have less than a clue about: a) Why the batch-file, after the final `y/n` confirmation, hangs with only one active command within `old.bat`, b) Given the `/S`, `/Q` and the specified directories were removed; why the two errors?

Respectfully

Comment: @Compo The 'goal' is to permanently delete all sub-dirs and their contents -eq and -lt the specified date. I copied this one-liner, studied it along with Forfiles /?. I understand better with full examples, vs only help-files. Removing the /S, results in "The directory is not empty.", then the script exits. The 'copied' script seemed to have a complete explanation of all its parameters, --with the exception of rd; I had to dig further for its usage.  Given the two versions of the script, I removed the /Q to slow the script; allow me to witness more of its behavior.

Comment: @Compo --removing the ``` Forfiles /S ``` has a positive effect. 1) It was part of the code I copied. 2) While comparing the copied code to ```Forfiles /?```, I thought the /S needed to be independent for both Forfiles and RD --since rd is within a quoted group of parameters. Given my lack of experience, there was no obvious speed-bump (to me). I'm not sure of the interaction between 'Forfiles /S' and 'rd /S/ that caused this issue, but it's behind me now. Thank you for pointing my brain in the right direction.

Comment: The working code: ``` ForFiles /p "X:\TEMP_TESTING_Copy" /d -03/26/2023 /c "cmd /c IF @isdir==TRUE rd /S /Q @PATH" ```